# Check status code for a request made via proxy using java

Tags: java, httpresponse, http-response-codes

I am trying to make an http request with proxy using Java and get the response code in an integer variable.

The method I am using is:

```
public static int getResponseCode(String urlString, Proxy p) throws MalformedURLException, IOException{
URL url = new URL(urlString);
HttpResponse urlresp = new DefaultHttpClient().execute(new HttpGet(urlString));
int resp_Code = urlresp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
return resp_Code;
}
```

I am passing a proxy parameter but I am not sure how to use it while making the request. I tried to look up resources online but was unable to find an apt solution.

I tried the below solution but was unsure how to get the response code here:

```
HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("proxy.com", 80, "http");
DefaultProxyRoutePlanner routePlanner = new DefaultProxyRoutePlanner(proxy);
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
                .setRoutePlanner(routePlanner)
                .build();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.myurl.com");

Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("proxy.com", 8080));

// IF NEED AUTH         
//      Authenticator authenticator = new Authenticator() {
//          public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
//              return (new PasswordAuthentication("username",
//                      "password".toCharArray()));
//          }
//      };
//      Authenticator.setDefault(authenticator);

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection(proxy);
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.connect();

        int code = conn.getResponseCode();

        System.out.println(code);
```